# HQL - Hibernate: How to get all records where day of endDate equals today

Tags: hibernate, repository, hql

What is the best way to get all records where the `endDate` has the same day, month and year as `today`?

I've tried multiple implementations like:

```
select i from Items i where day(i.endDate) = day(:today)
//today = ZonedDateTime.now()
```

the problem here is that the above query will retrieve all dates with the same day and also dates that are on the same day (example: day 20) but with a different month/year.

After searching on the internet for a while I haven't found a good solution yet. Has anyone implemented this before and can explain a solution?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this can be done by using the date_trunc function, but since Hibernate has no abstraction for this function, the easiest way to do this is to use a between predicate with proper start and end dates:

```
LocalDateTime firstOfMonth = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth( 1 ).atStartOfDay();
entityManager.createQuery("select i from Items i where i.endDate between :startDate and :endDate", Items.class)
  .setParameter("startDate", firstOfMonth)
  .setParameter("endDate", firstOfMonth.plusMonths( 1 ).minus( 1, ChronoUnit.SECONDS ))
```